# JSON_ARRAY_APPEND not inserting json document in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, sql-update, mysql-json

I have started using `MySQL 8` and trying to insert `JSON data type` in a `mysql table`

My `table t1` looks as below:

```
# id    type  jval
1100000 type1
```

I want to insert value for `jval` which is of type `JSON`.

```
UPDATE t1 mdata
        SET mdata.jval = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(jval, '$', JSON_OBJECT('user', 'user1', 'dept', 'dept1'))
        WHERE mdata.type = 'type1';
```

The above query is not inserting value for `jval`.

My table entry should look like below:

```
# id    type   jval
1100000 type1  [{"user": "user1", "dept": "dept1"}]
```

Comment: what is `value`?  where does that come from?  did you try `JSON_ARRAY_APPEND('[]', '$', ...`?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=093563932e0e69caef72b5757ebdaf72

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE t1 mdata
        SET mdata.jval = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND('[]', '$', JSON_OBJECT('user', 'user1', 'dept', 'dept1'))
        WHERE mdata.type = 'type1';
```